# snowflake grants for create table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to grant Create/Drop/Select/Insert/Delete/Truncate current & future table access to a role.

I did following still having problem.

```
grant usage on database TESTDB to role TEST_ROLE;
grant usage on schema TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE;
grant all on future tables in schema TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE;
grant all on all tables in schema TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE;

use role TEST_ROLE;
create table TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA.TESTTAB (name varchar(20);
```

SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TESTSCHEMA'

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Creating a table is an action performed in the context of a schema.
You need to use GRANT CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA ...

Comment: Thanks NickW. 
GRANT CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA DBA_EDMTEST.BASE_SCHEMA TO ROLE ROLE_DBATEST_ALL;

How about future grants? Do we needed? Can you please share the syntax. I assume same for "CREATE VIEW"

Comment: This grants the privilege to be able to create tables, therefore there is no concept of future grants as all create table statements would be in the future after being granted this role. Check the Snowflake documentation for the syntax

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking to give all permissions of the new schema `TESTSCHEMA` (except ownership or giving grant to other roles) to the new role `TEST_ROLE` then use:

```
grant ALL PRIVILEGES on schema TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE;
```

you may verify the privileges giving by

```
show grants to role TEST_ROLE;
```

If you think that is too much, then make a list exactly what you want out of the `SHOW` command result and try to write the REVOKE/GRANT new command following [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html) of the privileges you wanna revoke/grant and we can assist further?

Answer (score 2):

Below permissions need to be grant as per your requirement

Example
RoleName- **PRODUCTION_DBT**

USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN (Role with Super Privileges as AccountAdmin)

1. GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE  TO ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
2. GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE  TO ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
3. GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA . TO ROLE
   PRODUCTION_DBT
4. GRANT CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA . TO ROLE
   PRODUCTION_DBT
5. GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA . TO
   ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
6. GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE TABLES IN SCHEMA . TO
   ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
7. GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN .
    TO ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
8. GRANT TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA . TO
   ROLE PRODUCTION_DBT
9. GRANT CREATE VIEW ON SCHEMA . TO ROLE
   PRODUCTION_DBT
10. GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE ON SCHEMA . TO ROLE
    PRODUCTION_DBT

Answer (score 0):

Below grants will provide CURD access to a role.

```
grant usage on database…
grant usage on schema…
grant create table on schema….
--above will give CURD
grant select, insert, delete, ... on all tables in schema
--above grant will take care of all exists table grants
grant select, insert, delete, ... on future tables in schema
--above grant will take care of all future tables
```